# Solve the 1-dimensional heat equation with separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Solve the 1-dimensional heat equation subject to the boundary and the initial condition given by

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}, 0<x<1,t>0\\ u(0,t)=0, u( 1,t)=1, t>0\\u(x,0)=1-x , 0<x<1$$

Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ then the given pde into

$X(x)T'(t)=X''(x)T(t)\implies \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=k\\
X''(x)-kX(x)=0, T'(t)-kT(t)=0$

now $u(0,t)=X(0)T(t)=0\implies X(0)=0$ and
$u(1,t)=X(1)T(t)=1$

sorry I'm unable follow from here, any help?

Comment: I am not sure if you can solve this using seperation of variables due to the non-constant boundary conditions.

Comment: @DanDoe..I think so but im trying to solve using V and S

Comment: What are $V$ and $S$? Anyway I would suggest starting with $1-x=x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4}{2\pi n}\sin 2\pi n x$.

Comment: @InverseProblem I hope you mean to say $X,T$. Check my answer.

Comment: @Mathnerd. yeah.thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

To solve it using method of separation of variables, seek a particular solution of the form $u_{p}(x,t) = (1-0)x + 0 = x$ and consider the related homogeneous problem

$$ \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial x^{2}}, 0<x<1,t>0 $$
$$ v(0,t)=v(1,t)=0, t>0 $$
$$ v(x,0) = 1-x - u_{p}(x,0) = 1-2x, 0<x<1 .$$

Then the solution to given PDE will be $u(x,t) = u_{p}(x,t)+v(x,t).$

$\textbf{Full Solution:}$
Let $v(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$, then you will get
$$ X'' - kX=0, T'-kT=0. $$
Because $v(0,t)=v(1,t)=0$, implies $X(0)=X(1)$ otherwise we will get only trivial solution. Now, there will be three cases $k<0,k=0,k>0$. You can easily neglect two cases $k=0,k>0$ as only trivial solution will exist in these cases. So, take $k=-\lambda^2$ for $\lambda$ positive, then you will get
$$ X(x) = C_{1} \cos(\lambda x) + C_{2} \sin(\lambda x) $$ and using $X(0)=X(1)=0$, you will get $X_{n}(x) = a_{n} \sin(n \pi x).$ and $T_{n}(t) = b_{n}e^{-(n \pi)^{2}t}$. Therefore, $$v_{n}(x,t) =c_{n} \sin(n \pi x)e^{-(n \pi)^{2}t}. $$ Now, by principle of superposition

$$ v(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} \sin(n \pi x)e^{-(n \pi)^{2}t}.$$ Because $v(x,0) = 1-2x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} \sin(n \pi x) .$
$$ \implies c_{n} = 2 \int_{0}^{1}(1-2x) \sin(n \pi x) dx = 2\frac{(1+(-1)^n)}{n \pi}. $$ So, we have
$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2\frac{(1+(-1)^n)}{n \pi} e^{-(n \pi)^{2}t}\sin(n \pi x) + x. $$

Comment: That can't be right. If $u_{p}(x,t)=x$ and $v(x,0)=1$ then $u(x,0)=u_{p}(x,0)+v(x,0)=1+x$.

Comment: OK. But I'm still not sure it will be "easy" to go on to find a solution using separation of variables. I suspect it's only possible using a Fourier decomposition as I suggested in my comment above.

Comment: @Ali I have given full solution, I hope now it is clear to you.

Comment: Well I plotted your answer for $t=0$. And yes one thing at least is clear to me.  It's not good.

Comment: Your comments look biased to me, it does not matter if it looks good to you or not. It should be correct. Learn to respect Mathematics. Btw, why not you post your answer, instead of giving hint.

Comment: I apologise. I made an error typing into Mathematica. It's true that I was too quick to assume you had made another mistake. (I see you have deleted your comment admitting the first.) I have not checked your working but see now that your answer matches mine (given in the comments) for the case $t=0$. Mine is a little simpler because by putting $2\pi$ instead of $\pi$ inside the $\sin$ term, one doesn't need to drop the odd terms by means of $(1+(-1)^{n})$.

Comment: That's true, the expression given by you for $u(x,0)$ matches with $u(x,0)$ obtained from my solution.